# Trying to access an .stl file using MDLAssets from iCloud but .startAccessingSecurityScopedResource() is allows false

Tags: ios, icloud, scenekit, file-access

Im trying to load a modal into a ARKit Scene which works on top of SceneKit but I'm trying to load a .stl file from iCloud using a UIDocumentPickerViewController which allowed me to save the file Urls into core data for later use. The CoreData Entity is displayed on a TableView for Selection, when I tap one of the items it should load into the scene but `url.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()` seems to always be false or without the if statement containing `.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()` it crashes at `asset.Object(at: 0)`

here's the func code:

```
func loadModalToScene(url: URL) {

    print("Can Open: ", MDLAsset.canImportFileExtension(url.absoluteString))
    if (url.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()) {

        //Loads 3D Objects into Memory via Model / IO
        let asset = MDLAsset(url: url)
        print("MDL Asset: ", asset)

        // Turns the MDLAsset into a MDLObject
        let object = asset.object(at: 0)
        print("Object Asset: ", object)

        // Turns the MDLObject into a SCNNode
        let node = SCNNode(mdlObject: object)
        print("SCN Node Asset: ", node)

        url.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
    }
}
```

the function isn't feature complete but I'm trying first to load it into memory.

Comment: This isn't really an ARKit question if you're stuck on file I/O before you event start with the AR part. Have you checked to see if you can even read the file with `Data`? If not, then Model I/O and SceneKit aren't your problem— file access is.

Comment: I think its file access since I'm loading the file URL straight to Model I/O